# add functional icon in google map link that i want to email

Tags: google-maps

I have spent hours searching for the answer, forgive me if it was right in front of me.

I want to send an email with a google map link
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=address 
(I got this from an answer in stackoverflow.)

In his iphone, the reader taps the link in the email, the map opens, 
The reader taps Directions, then Route,
And the route, time and distance appear in the map from the reader’s current location to the map address above.

Now – I want to include an icon visible on a corner of the map view that reads “I’ll be there.”     When the reader taps that icon in the map, the end result is the reader responds in the email to the sender “I’ll be there.”

How hard is this to program?
The intermediary physical steps are  - Tap main iphone button to main screen.   Tap email.   Tap respond arrow.   Tap Reply.   Type “I’ll be there.”   Tap Send.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at embedding a map into your own web page using the Google Maps v3 API. The link in your question is a web page rendered by Google. You will want to control the rendering to add your button. I don't know of any other way.

Bob

[Update] Here is a jsFiddle using the API to render a map. http://jsfiddle.net/JsAJA/3/

Comment: Thank you. I hoped to include this as a program to be sent with the the link in the email. When the link was opened in the iphone map to show the locations, the icon with shortcuts would open in the map. this may be way over my level.